# Array as Model for Service Breaks when Empty

Tags: angularjs, arrays, service, model

I have two routes: one has a custom component that repeats the data in an array and allows the user to add and remove items, the other route only displays the model. The model is stored in a service. The model JSON data looks like this:

```
[
    {name: "one"},
    {name: "two"},
    {name: "three"}
]
```

The components are all using `ng-model` and assigning `this` to a variable `vm`. Following all the best practices from John Papa style guide.

If I empty the array either by using `slice()`, `pop()`, or setting the array length to 0, it breaks.  You can still add data to it, but if you navigate to the other route, the model will show as an empty array. And if you navigate back again, the array is still empty.

If I make my model an object with a key and the array as the value, everything works as expected.  So my question is, is this just a limitation or am I doing something wrong?

```
{
    myarray: [
        {name: "one"},
        {name: "two"},
        {name: "three"}
    ]
}
```

Here is the [working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/o4hJsGijT14NFS4WgE0R) using the object containing the array.

And here is the [non working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/ulMo1pRqdEwRPdgzt8sa) just using the array.

You'll see on the one that does not work, you'll empty the array and then add to it, it will not persist data across the routes.

Comment: Code or it didn't happen

Comment: You said service breaks and what's this meaning? can you share the fiddle for more understanding?

Comment: @MikeFeltman I added plunkr of it working and not working as I described

Comment: @artgbI I mean that the model in the service no longer persists data in the array (if it has been emptied and then added to)  after changing route

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> you'll empty the array and then add to it, it will not persist data across the routes

#### 1st Problem:  in `getAsync()` method.

When your `model` is empty you call `callAtInterval()` every 100 milliseconds and you never resolve your promise (infinite loop).

```
function getAsync() {         
        function callAtInterval() {
            if (!_.isEmpty(genericHttpModel.model)){
                $interval.cancel(promise);
                deferred.resolve(get());
            }                
        }
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var promise = $interval(callAtInterval, 100);
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Therefore when user goes to `home` (`root`) route:

```
 genericHttpService.getAsync().then(function(model){
      vm.model = model; // <-- never called 
    });
```

So remove `if (!_.isEmpty(genericHttpModel.model))` statement

```
function callAtInterval() {                
     $interval.cancel(promise);
     deferred.resolve(get());
    }                
}
```

---

#### 2nd  problem: in `add` method:

```
 function add() {
       if (modelEmpty()) {
         initModelAndAddOne();
       } else {
        vm.model.push({});
      }
    }
```

In `initModelAndAddOne` you reset original instance of `vm.model` with:

```
 vm.model = [];
```

Your model is already empty, why to redefine it with `=[]`, make it simple:

```
 function add() {
   vm.model.push({});
  }
```

<kbd>[Working Example Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/E97FujEEb6uwRRMHdtPA?p=preview)</kbd>

---

> [working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/o4hJsGijT14NFS4WgE0R) using the object containing the array.

So why it works:

- 1st off `_.isEmpty(genericHttpModel.model)` will always return `false` because object contains field `names` a.e: `genericHttpModel.model = {names:[]}`
- 2nd - `vm.model = []` resets `names` field only and not service object

Comment: This is a very nice/helpfull answer !

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering this.  
What you labeled as the 2nd problem was the answer for my question.
What you labeled as the 1st problem was a nice catch.  The reason that happened was because originally I had it as an array, so code would actually return the correct result because it would be an array not an object with a nested array.

Comment: any idea why in service.js fetch function angular.copy causes the error "destination.push is not a function" ?

Comment: @nilloc I believe you wanted `genericHttpModel.model = angular.copy(response.data);` or  destination should be the same type as source: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

Comment: @MaximShoustin thank you, i see now that i had the model being manually defined as an object at the top.